# Organizing projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

For school I have a lot of projects in my project explorer in Eclipse, and I was wondering if it was possible to put them in folders (in eclipse)

for example:
Folder Chapter 1

- project exercise 1
- project exercise 2
  Folder Chapter 3
- project exercise 3
  ...

Comment: they are called working sets.

Comment: Have you even searched on the internet? -> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=eclipse+organizing+folders

Comment: Yes I looked up on the internet, but the only thing I found whas packages.
An Thank you njzk2, I'll look for it tonight :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Package Explorer view you can organize your projects using Working Set

To configure working set open view menu and select "Configure Working Sets..." then to turn it on open one more time and select "Top Level Element" and choose "Working Sets".

Comment: Thanks A lot! I'll look for it tonight :)